# Webdriverio -- Elements doesn't work

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to use Elements to get an array of elements, but it doesn't work here.

Any one can help me with that? thanks a lots.

here is my code:

```
<select name="test" id="select">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Now I am trying to get all the option elements:

```
client.url('www.somesite.com')
  .elements('#select>option').then(function(res){
       console.log(res.length);
    })
```

But I got 'undefined' result for 'res.length' .

If I use getText then I can get the correct result:

```
 client.url('www.somesite.com')
  .getText('#select>option').then(function(res){
       console.log(res.length);
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the `value` property.

```
console.log(res.value.length);
```